# Using fonts with older apps (ctwm, ical), and finding more fonts to use

Tags: fonts

I am using various old/legacy tools, such as `ctwm` and `ical`, which appear to prefer the fonts -- specifically, the font ***names*** -- returned by `xlsfonts`, instead of `fc-list`.  That is, if I specify a font name output by `xlsfonts`, like

```
 charter-bold-r-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-adobe-standard
```

then `ctwm` and `ical` will use it.  On the other hand, if I specify a font name output by `fc-list`, like

```
 Palladio
```

then those programs will ignore the specification and use a default font.

Unfortunately, the `xlsfonts` fonts are rather limited.  For example, there is no "helvetica" font.

Note that I am working with a basic install of 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), with a number of application packages subsequently installed through `apt-get`.  As far as I know, I am only using the font packages that come with that basic installation.  Previously, I used 10.04 (Lucid Lynx) and had access to many more fonts (including Helvetica).

So, my questions are:

1. Can I use the `fc-list` fonts with these older packages?  If so, how?
2. If I'm limited to just the `xlsfonts` fonts, then are there additional packages that I should install?
3. Am I missing something fundamental about these fonts and how they work?  If so, what?

Thanks!

Bob

Answer (score 0):

They use different systems and point to different directories, I refer you to [this discussion](http://www.linux.com/community/forums/desktop/xlsfonts-cant-see-fonts-that-chkfontpath-has-listed?limit=6&offset=6) on linux.com for more explanations.

Coming back to your problem, what you want to do is that the X font system management indexes also the other folder, like the new system does.

Unfortunately this is not straight-forward.
The X system uses bitmap font formats (according to [this](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/fonts/X-Window-System-fonts.html)), so in principle you cannot use .ttf files straight away.

First you have to convert them to any of the formats stated above and then you can follow that guide to add them all to the underlying X system.

Please not that I did not try it, but also [this other source](http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/XFonts.html) seems pertinent here. You probably just have to pay attention that `ttmkfdir` does not exists anymore and it has been replaced (a long time ago, according to [this](https://freshports.org/x11-fonts/ttmkfdir/)) by `mkfontdir` and `mkfontscale`.