# passing a font as an argument to a script

Tags: command-line, scripts, fonts

I am trying to use osdSH for notifications.

It has a 'font' parameter that receives a curiously formed string. From the man:

```
-f -font
             Set          font         (Default:         -*-lucidatypewriter-
             bold-*-*-*-*-240-*-*-*-*-*-*)
```

The manual does not comment on the arguments passed (I assume each * represents a possible argument). It would seem that this notation is (or has someday been) standard, but I've not been able to find anything about it.

what is the standard ?
what argument specifies letter size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [X logical font description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_logical_font_description). See the [full standard at x.org](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/XLFD/xlfd.html)

The 7th field specifies the size in pixel, the 8th the size in tenths of points.

So the default here is "lucidatypewriter bold at 24 point".

You can use `xfontsel` as a simple GUI to create such font descriptions.

Comment: I had very small chars. Looking at xfontsel, it seems that the default font for the program was not available, and I was getting some sort of (very small) system default

Comment: @josinalvo Yes --- the default used to be "fixed", which is normally a monospaced font sized 5x7 or 6x13. You can see it in `/etc/X11/fonts/misc/xfonts-base.alias`; "fixed" is defined here to be `-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1`. This come from a time when 640x480 was hi-res...

Comment: A followup question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/514108/fonts-that-appear-on-xfontsel-vs-other-fonts

Comment: In my ignorance, I cannot tell if my question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/247676/using-fonts-with-older-apps-ctwm-ical-and-finding-more-fonts-to-use