# fonts that appear on xfontsel VS "other fonts"

Tags: fonts

I am looking for good fonts to use on osdSH

As far as I can tell (see [passing a font as an argument to a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514000/passing-a-font-as-an-argument-to-a-script)) these are the fonts xfontsel lists to me

These, unfortunately, seem rather limited (and more, seem to have diminished from 12.04 to 14.04). Also, they are limited in size (the biggest one is 32 px, the biggest one on 12.04 was 34)

Now, I found other fonts elsewhere (for example, following http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1021). Using those instructions, I found, in my system, a lot of fonts, in all sizes (well... at least up to 60 px)

I presume they are fonts "of a different kind". My question: can I use these nice, 60px fonts on my original aplication ? Can I find more (and bigger) "xfontsel" fonts elsewhere ?

---

Regarding the bounty, things I'd like to understand:
 1. the different systems that manage fonts 
 2. which of these systems is relevant for xfontsel
 
 3. which of these systems is relevant for osdSH (the same ?)
 4. a way to get more fonts for 2 and 3

Comment: In my ignorance, I cannot tell if my question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/247676/using-fonts-with-older-apps-ctwm-ical-and-finding-more-fonts-to-use

Comment: Necroposting OK here? Xfontsel seems to have aquired a bug that can limit it to showing fonts under a certain pxlsz. I don't know what circumstances kick the effect in. I know I have at least one 64 pxlsz font and I'm using it in 9menu. I got the string from xfontsel which a few weeks ago showed fonts up to 64 pxlsz. I installed more fonts and now it won't show anything over 40.